# How can I connect to a local SQL server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to create my own database with my tables to practice some SQL. I cannot create a database unless i connect to a server. I have tried Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and MySQL Workbench but both failed.

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I tried:

- Server Type: Database Engine
- Server Name: "DESKTOP-MUO9FQ2" and "." and "local"
- Authentication: Windows Authentication
- *GRAYED OUT:*
- Username: DESKTOP-MUO9FQ2\15072
- Password:

In MySQL Workbench:

- Connection Name: localhost
- Host Name: 127.0.0.1
- Port: 3306 and 1433
- Username: root

How can I connect to any server so I can create my own database and play around with my data using SQL?

Comment: First step is to decide whether to use mySQL, an Oracle product, or sql-server from Microsoft

Comment: I just want to create the database with the tables and use SQL on that data. I do not care which product to use

Comment: And you will need to create a database server instance before you can do anything. For sql server, SSMS is just an application used to manage server instances - you must install the instance separately.

Comment: Have you installed a database? E.g. you can get a "Developer" or "Express" version for free from Microsoft: search for "sql server download".

Comment: You need to install mysql or sql-server. Since those are different products with (slightly) different syntax, you should care about which to use.

Comment: The easiest to get started is using docker, https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql. You can create an instance with `docker run --name some-mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest
`

Comment: Did you work with docker before?

Comment: thank you @Andrew-Morton your solution worked!!

Comment: @SalmaAbdelhamid You're welcome :) I voted to close this question because the problem was more of a typo than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I installed MySql which includes MySql CLI, and it works fine.

You just have to [install MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/) and you will have the CLI includes.

In the installation, you will have to define a root user and a user each with password.
Then run MySql CLI and you will have to enter the root password you choose, and then it's done.

Now you can can create databases ,tables and so on...